# C# / MongoDB Deserialization of Array of Array of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am attempting to create an array of array of dictionaries in ASP.NET Core using MongoDB. In the end, the data should retain this model for all uses:

**Model**

```
{
    "ContextName": "Base rates",
    "Indexes": [
        {
            "IndexName": "S&P",
            "IndexValues" : [
                {
                    "Date": "2019-01-01",
                    "Value": "2600.98"
                },
                {
                    "Date": "2019-01-02",
                    "Value": "2605.98"
                }              
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, I have my first layer defined below encompassing the `ContextName` and `Indexes`:

**Context.cs**

```
public class Context
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ContextName")]
        public string ContextName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Indexes")]
        public ICollection<Index> Indexes { get; set; }
    }
```

With `Index` having the following structure:

**Index.cs**

```
public class Index
    {
        [BsonElement("IndexName")]
        public string IndexName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("IndexValues")]
        [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
        public Dictionary<DateTime, double> IndexValues { get; set; }
    }
```

Running this code I am met with a Format Exception stating

> An error occurred while deserializing the IndexValues property of
>   class Database.Index: Invalid element: 'Date'.'

My first thought is that it is an issue with the key being of type `Date` and not of `string` within the database itself, however I have read [here towards the bottom](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-44) that the official driver supports this actually.

I went a bit further to try and set some custom `{ get; set; }` to bring in the key as a string but am being met with the same error in the end.

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, double> IndexValues
        {
            get
            {
                Dictionary<DateTime, double> _indexValues = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
                foreach (var indexValue in IndexValues)
                {
                    _indexValues.Add(indexValue.Key, indexValue.Value);
                }
                return _indexValues;
            }
            set { IndexValues = IndexValues; } // Unsure about here as well
        }
```

I am unsure what to be looking at for this case, and am looking for some pointers to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

### **Update**

Formatting the dictionary in an external method allows for the correct format, however also inserts one extra field as it is used in gathering all the required information.

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, double> IndexValuesDictionary
        {
            get { return SetDictionary(); }
            set { SetDictionary(); }
        }

        private Dictionary<DateTime, double> SetDictionary()
        {
            if (_indexValues == null)
            {
                _indexValues = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
                foreach (var indexValue in IndexValues)
                {
                    _indexValues.Add(indexValue.Date, indexValue.Value);
                }
            }
            return _indexValues;
        }
```

```
{
        "id": "5c93c1123369220b685719b3",
        "contextName": "Base rates",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "indexName": "S&P",
                "indexValues": [
                    {
                        "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "value": 2600.98
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z",
                        "value": 2605.98
                    }
                ],
                "indexValuesDictionary": { // This should not be included
                    "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z": 2600.98,
                    "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z": 2605.98
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is this the only viable option for this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a step back and looking at the data structure, I was able to get this working by removing the array nesting and working solely with document nesting (unfortunate but simplifies the schema). The updated database structure is:

```
[
    {
        "ContextName": "Base rates",
        "Description": "Base rates description",
        "Indexes": {
            "SPX": {
                "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z": 2600.98
            },
            "NDX": {
                "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z": 6600.98
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Leaving the class structures updated as:

**Context.cs**

```
public class Context
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ContextName")]
        public string ContextName { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Indexes")]
        [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
        public Index Indexes { get; set; }
    }
```

**Index.cs**

```
public class Index : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>> { }
```

I also changed the serializer to treat `DateTime` as a `string` instead, and so included this in the program startup:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Local, BsonType.String));
```

These changes allow the structure to be formatted correctly.